# Use tapi32.dll methods which takes source and destination phone number

Tags: c#, tapi

I consume the `tapi32.dll` to make a function in such way that it should ask me for a *from* extension phone number and a *to* extension phone number.

I require that the source and destination phone numbers are entered manually to then get a call connected.

This is the method call I am using:

```
[DllImport("tapi32.dll")]
public static extern int tapiRequestMakeCall(
    string destAddress,
    string appName,
    string calledParty,
    string comment);
```

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: Is it possible .?

Comment: You should provide your current code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Take the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to understand how to ask effective questions here

Comment: [DllImport("tapi32.dll")]
         public static extern int tapiRequestMakeCall(string destAddress, string appName, string calledParty, string comment);                                               Am using above method to make a call

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with tapiRequestMakeCall. This function only delegates the call to a another application that finally places the call.

If you want to do this all by your own, you need to do more than just calling this function. Below the description for Tapi 1.x and 2.x

1. lineOpen to open a line. With this call you already defined the "from" extension, with the line you are opening.
2. You need to call lineMakeCall. Again you have choices here to select a line and/or address. Again this may defined the from extension (depends on your TSP)
3. With lineMakeCall you may offer some LINECALLPARAMS were you can define more dteails to the call you are placing.

Using Tapi 3.0 (COM interface) is identical to the above. In this case you have corresponding objects to open a line and place a call.